# Java @Inject null pointer between modules and ServiceLoader

Tags: java, dependency-injection, cdi

I have three maven modules:

1. **Commons module:** common operations
2. **Provider module:** specific implementations to extract data.
3. **Main module:** make use of the provider modules.

The sequence works like this:

- The *main module* receives a request, and there's an interface which manages providers (`Client`) and load providers using `ServiceLoader.load(Provider.class)`.
- My `Client` extracts data (`client.retrieveData(request)`) selecting the adequate provider.
- A provider implements a method `buildRequest()`.

And here's my problem: Support classes from commons module are used in the other two modules. I can use all classes I've injected in my main module, but classes injected in a provider module have a null pointer. For example, this is an implementation of a  provider class:

```
public class ScholarProvider extends AbstractProvider {

    @Inject
    private DistanceService distance;
    @Inject
    private final Logger log;
    public static final String URL = "https://scholar.google.com";

    private MapperObjectRDF mapper;

    private String[] domains;
    private Person person;

    public ScholarProvider() {
        person = null;
        mapper = null;
    }
}
```

In `ScholarProvider`—and in any other provider—distance and log are null. I cannot understand where is the problem. Could it be the problem for loading providers through `ServiceLoader`? Any suggestions what could be the problem? or is there any possible solution that I could use my `DistanceService` with a new instantiation?

Comment: Your problem is here:`ServiceLoader.load(Provider.class)` Loading a class through the ServiceLoader does not automatically register it with the CDI container.

Secondly,  if you want to go through the route of selecting classes during deployment, then mark all your providers with `@Alternative` and enable the alternative you wish from `beans.xml`, the CDI way

Answer (score 0):

Does your cdi framework know that the provider is a bean to do injection on?  If you are using Spring, you need to annotate the class with either `@Named` or any spring specific annotation that inherits from `@Componenent` and then make sure you scan that class.  If your framework does not know about your bean, it won't do any injections.

Comment: I tried adding `@Named` annotation to scholar provider, and it doesn't work. I cannot modify `AbstractProvider` because it's a class from a maven dependency.

Comment: Is your cdi framework scanning that package or otherwise know that class is a bean?

Comment: How can I check if my cdi framework is scanning that class? Yes, it's a bean.

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is not how CDI works.  In a CDI fashion, you would define each of the classes and give them qualifiers.  Then you would inject them using qualifiers.

So instead of using `ServiceLoader.load()` you would inject the reference, something like this

```
@Inject
@Named("the name")
private Provider provider
```

Comment: I cannot change the `ServiceLoader.load()` because it's code from another library. In my main module the inject works, I was thinking as a complementary solution pass a reference of inject variables to each provider in a set method.

Comment: You could also do what `injectFields` does from DeltaSpike - https://github.com/apache/deltaspike/blob/master/deltaspike/core/api/src/main/java/org/apache/deltaspike/core/api/provider/BeanProvider.java#L460